# Unable to see a detailed report running pylint in mac terminal

Tags: pylint

I do have `pylint` installed to the latest version, however when running `pylint myfile.py -r` nothing is executed as shown in the screenshot attached.  [you can see that I have pylint installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfHkN.jpg)

If anyone can help me to locate an issue here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does running `pylint myfile.py --enable=all` prints something?

Answer (score 1):

The -r option requires an argument. The possible arguments are *y* and *n*.

To get a detailed report, the command should be:

```
pylint myfile.py -r y
```